# asp.net ajax updated the controltoolkit version resolves in error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

since i switched computers i copied the solution and thought it was a nice time to change the ajaxtoolkit.dll with a new version. so i downloaded the latest version and added the reference. when i compile, there is nothing wrong in visual studio 2008. (it's a webapplication) 
but when it runs i get a: there are multiple controls with the same id. 
i found out that when i disabled the ajax accordion control it runs well.

i found the solution on this website: http://forums.asp.net/t/1457688.aspx

but now i can't use the accordion control... how can i update the accordion control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the accordion an ID from the codeBehind. I think it'll solve your problem.

(That's how I work with Accordion and Framework 3.5 + recent toolkit).

Comment: it is the toolkit release from nobember and i have multiple accordion panels

Comment: ok changed it back to http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=33804
instead of asp.net ajax 4.0 with all the javascripts etc.